How can I disable the connection to the db when I try to run a dag for Airflow within a unit test?
I am running something similar to this (from the Documentation):
import datetime

import pendulum
import pytest

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.state import DagRunState, TaskInstanceState
from airflow.utils.types import DagRunType

DATA_INTERVAL_START = pendulum.datetime(2021, 9, 13, tz="UTC")
DATA_INTERVAL_END = DATA_INTERVAL_START + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

TEST_DAG_ID = "my_custom_operator_dag"
TEST_TASK_ID = "my_custom_operator_task"


@pytest.fixture()
def dag():
    with DAG(
        dag_id=TEST_DAG_ID,
        schedule="@daily",
        start_date=DATA_INTERVAL_START,
    ) as dag:
        MyCustomOperator(
            task_id=TEST_TASK_ID,
            prefix="s3://bucket/some/prefix",
        )
    return dag


def test_my_custom_operator_execute_no_trigger(dag):
    dagrun = dag.create_dagrun(
        state=DagRunState.RUNNING,
        execution_date=DATA_INTERVAL_START,
        data_interval=(DATA_INTERVAL_START, DATA_INTERVAL_END),
        start_date=DATA_INTERVAL_END,
        run_type=DagRunType.MANUAL,
    )
    ti = dagrun.get_task_instance(task_id=TEST_TASK_ID)
    ti.task = dag.get_task(task_id=TEST_TASK_ID)
    ti.run(ignore_ti_state=True)
    assert ti.state == TaskInstanceState.SUCCESS
    # Assert something related to tasks results.

but in my case, when I run it in my environment, I get the error:

def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError:
(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such
table: dag_run E       [SQL: INSERT INTO dag_run (dag_id, queued_at,
execution_date, start_date, end_date, state, run_id, creating_job_id,
external_trigger, run_type, conf, data_interval_start,
data_interval_end, last_scheduling_decision, dag_hash,
log_template_id, updated_at, clear_number) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, (SELECT max(log_template.id) AS max_1  E
FROM log_template), ?, ?)]

How can I disable that connection and/or avoid that error?
